# How to pass additional arguments in an associative table that reference to the parent and child model

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm creating a database that uses two tables that have many-to-many relationships. Here's a my associative table:

```
Runner = db.Table('runner',
  db.Column('foo_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Foo.id'), primary_key=True),
  db.Column('bar_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Bar.id'), primary_key=True),
  db.Column('foo_name', db.String, db.ForeignKey("Foo.name")),
  db.Column('foo_age', db.String, db.ForeignKey("Foo.age")),
  db.Column('bar_name', db.String, db.ForeignKey('Bar.name')))
```

My two main models:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Foo'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'age')
```

```
class Bar(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Bar'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    db.UniqueConstraint('name')
```

Flask migrations run but an error is thrown when I run `flask db upgrade`:
*sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidForeignKey) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Foo"*.

How can I reference other columns in the table that are not primary keys?

Comment: You don't. An association *table* only contains the foreign keys that match the primary keys in the related objects. If you want to store additional attributes about the link between the two objects then you would use an association *object*, but even that would not include attributes that are specific to the objects themselves. You get those attributes (e.g., age) when you perform a query.

Comment: Okay. So assuming I'm using an Association object, how will I query data from the two models? I'm kind of lost at this point @GordThompson

Comment: Got it. I implemented it using an association table. Then used unique and not null constraints on the columns that need to be referenced.